# How to convert associative array to key:value?

Tags: json, d, vibed

I need to convert associative array, to put them to Json, but I can't understanf how to do it. Method `to!string` add unnecessary slashes.

```
int[string] name;
name["Python"] = 5;
Json tags = Json.emptyObject; //Json object
tags["tags"] = name.to!string;
writeln(tags);
```

`{"tags":"[\"Python\":1]"}`

I need to get: `{"tags":{"Python":1}}`

Also I am thinking about using `tuples` so if there is any solution for them I would like to look at it.

Comment: You need to get invalid json?

Comment: Try running it in a validator, what's the purpose in the odd number of quotes?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow didn't notice your vibed keyword - deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`to!string` is the wrong approach. You don't want to convert to a generic string, but to JSON.

My first idea would be `tags["tags"] = name;`. But vibe.d's `JSON` doesn't seem to have an `opAssign` that takes a generic associative array.

Second idea, loop over `name` and assign its items to `tags["name"]`:

```
import vibe.data.json;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    int[string] name;
    name["Python"] = 5;
    Json tags = Json.emptyObject; //Json object

    tags["tags"] = Json.emptyObject;
    foreach (k, v; name) tags["tags"][k] = v;

    writeln(tags);
}
```

Comment: Would it be easier with tuples (or AliasSeq, as they are named now)?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you'd do with tuples here (regardless whether std.typecons.Tuple or std.meta.AliasSeq).

Comment: I can't understand what difference between std.typecons.Tuple and std.meta.AliasSeq ...

Comment: This comment section isn't really suited for longer explanations or discussions. Please post a new question, though I'm not sure if it's a good fit for Stack Overflow. Or post in [D's learn forum](http://forum.dlang.org/group/learn).