# What is the best way to convert structure to Json?

Tags: json, serialization, d

I am still looking for best way to converting my date to Json. I need to get structure like this:

`"tags": {
    "Python": 1,
    "Java": 3,
    "Linux": 8
  }`

My first attempted was to use associative array for it:
[How to convert associative array to key:value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680906/how-to-convert-associative-array-to-keyvalue)

but later I understood that it's not best variant. So I decided to create array of structures.

Next code is just create test array of structures and fill it's with test data:

```
struct MyData
    {
        string name;
        int value;
    }

    MyData [] mydata;
    string mystr = "qwert";

    foreach (i; 1..5)
    {
        MyData md;
        md.name = to!(string)(mystr[i]) ~ to!(string)(mystr[i]); // just to have double letters like: "qq"
        md.value = i;
        mydata ~= md;
    }
```

So in next step I can iterate array of structures with `foreach`, and create proper json with string concatination like:

```
    string tagsList = `"` ~ data.name ~ `":` ~ to!string(data.value) ~ `,`;
    write(tagsList);
```

And result will be like:

`"ww":1,"ee":2,"rr":3,"tt":4,`

But it's look very dirty code, and I would need to cut comma symbol at the end.

I googled and found several modules like `painlessjson` that allow me to do serialization of structure to json, but it's work in different manner. It's took name of element in structure and I am getting something like:
`{"name":"ww","value":1}`

So what language future should I use to get proper result?

Comment: The trick to the comma btw is not to cut it at the end, but only put it on if you aren't the first entry. Think of the comma not as the end but as the beginning and it becomes easier to code.

Comment: Adam, sorry I don't understand you. What you mean by "Think of the comma not as the end but as the beginning and it becomes easier to code". Also do my idea with creation such string by hand is good or it's bad practice?

Comment: For the creation of the string, you'd probably be better off with std.json or some other library like @Nested type's answer, because then it will be sure to properly escape names with other characters and stuff like that, and probably be a bit more efficient too. (I didn't write that yesterday cuz I was in a rush to get out the door when I commented.) But if you are building a string yourself, see this file explaining it in more detail with an example: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/comma.d You'd probably want to use a library for your problem but this approach of rethinking can help simplify a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a custom serialization routine for your struct is not a big problem using `std.json`.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.json;

struct Data
{
    string name;
    int value;
    void serialize(ref JSONValue jv)
    {
        jv[name] = value;
    }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    Data[] data = [Data("a",1), Data("b",2)];
    JSONValue obj = parseJSON("{}");
    foreach(Data d; data)
        d.serialize(obj);
    writeln(obj.toPrettyString);
}
```

As you can see the code is clean, one single LOC to write. It prints in the format you expect:

> {
>      "a": 1,
>      "b": 2
>   }

Comment: thanks! 
Just interesting is it's possible to do with D modern futures like onApply, onAssign etc?

Comment: what ? I don't get what you mean. What are modern futures  ? you mean calling a delegate in an operator overload function ?

Comment: I named futures like onApply, onAssign etc "modern". It's hard for me to understand which tasks they can to solve. So I am just ask to understand if they can be used for this task.

Comment: opApply, opAssign are operator overload. They are used in custom types (struct, classes) to allow the usage of D keywords and symbols such as  **+**  **-** **=** **/** **foreach** etc. In a way it's just syntactic sugar since it's stricly the same as calling a member function. In your case this could be used for example if you write `void opAssign(T)(T t) if (is(T==JSONVvalue)) {}` to deserialize.